# Allowing user-created templates in an ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, templates, user-input

I have a website I’m converting from Classic ASP to ASP.NET.  The old site allowed users to edit the website template to create their own design for their section of the website (think MySpace, only LESS professional.)

I’ve been racking my brain trying to figure out how to do this with .NET.  My sites generally use master pages, but obviously that won’t work for end-users.

I’ve tried loading the HTML templates as a regular text file and parsing it to ‘fit around’  the content place holders.  It is as ugly as it sounds.

There’s got a be something generally regarded as the best practice here, but I sure can’t find it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How much control do you want your users to have?

There are a few ways to implement this. I'll give you a quick summary of all the ideas I can think of:

#### Static HTML with predefined fields.

With this approach you get full control and you minimize the risk of any security vulnerabilities. You would store per-user HTML in a database table somewhere. This HTML would have predefined fields with some markup, like using `{fieldName}`. You would then use a simple parser to identify curly brackets and replace `fieldName` with a string value pulled from a `Dictionary<String,String>` somewhere.

This approach can be fast if you're smart with string processing (i.e. using a state-machine parser to find the curley brackets, sending the rebuilt string either directly to the output or into a StringBuilder, etc, and importantly *not* using `String.Replace`). The downside is it isn't a real templating system: there's no provision for looping over result-sets (assuming you want to allow that), expression evaluation, but it works for simple "insert this content into this space"-type designs.

#### Allow users to edit their own ASPX or ASCX files.

Why build your own templating system if you can use ASP.NET's? Well, this approach is the simplest if you want to build a quick 'n' dirty reporting system, but it fails terribly for security. Unfortunately you cannot secure any `<% %>` / `<script runat="server">` code in ASPX files in a sandbox or use CAS owing to how ASP.NET works (I looked into this myself earlier: [Code Access Security on a per-view ASP.NET MVC basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943888/code-access-security-on-a-per-view-asp-net-mvc-basis) ).

You don't need to store the actual ASPX and ASCX files in the website's filesystem, you can store the files in your database using a `VirtualPathProvider` implementation, but getting it to work right can be a bit of a pain (especially as the ASP.NET runtime compiles ASPX files, so you'd need to inform it if an ASPX file was modified by the user). You also need to be aware that ASPX loading is tied into the user's request path (unless you're using Routing or MVC) so you're better off using ASCX, not that it matters really.

#### A custom ASP.NET handler that runs in its own CAS sandbox that implements a fully-fledged templating engine

This is the most painful option, and it exists between the two: you get the flexibility of a first-class templating engine (loops, fields, evaluation if necessary) without needing to open your application up to gaping security flaws. The downside is you need to build pretty much everything by yourself. I won't go into detail here.

Which option you go for depends on what your requirements are. MySpace's system was more "skinning" than "templating", in that the users were free to set a stylesheet and define some arbitrary common HTML rather than modify their page's general template directly.

You can easily implement a MySpace-like system in ASP.NET assuming that each skinnable feature is implemented as a `Control` subclass, just extend your `Render` method to allow for the insertion of said arbitrary HTML. Adding custom stylesheets is also easy: just add it inside a `<style type="text/css">` element in your page's `<head>`.

When/if you do allow the user to enter HTML directly, I strongly recommend you parse it and filter out any dangerous elements (such as `<script>`, `<style>`, `<object>`, etc). If you want to allow for the embedding of YouTube videos and related then you should analyse `<object>` elements to ensure they actually are of YouTube videos, extract the video ID, then recreate the element from a known, trusted template. It is important that any custom HTML is "tag-balanced" (you can verify this by passing it through a strict XML parser instead of a more forgiving HTML parser, as XHTML is (technically) a subset of HTML anyway), that way any custom markup won't break the page.

Have fun.